# How to call sequence of call in node->Expreess ^4.14

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, synchronization

I have requirements to search given "key" in API returned response. I have to invoke same API multiple times with different inputs.
Upon getting the response from API , i need to search KEY in API response. If the KEY is not present then invoke the same API again with different input and search ...continue .

Basically , until i complete one iteration of searching the KEY in API response, the execution should wait . How can achieve this ?  Please suggest.

I have tried with below approach and execution not waiting until it search keys in API response.

```
for (i=0;i< departments.length;i++)                                                                       
{
   getInformation(departments[i]).
    then((response) => {
    //verify whether given key present in response
    
    })
    .catch((err)) => {
 //log error
 });

}// end of for loop
}
```

Note: I would like to continue the Search operation with next keys even if their is any exception in one of the API call.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You've to use recursivity

```
let departments = [xxx]
let myResult = []

const search = (pool, resolve, reject) => {
        if (pool.length === 0) {
           return resolve()
        }

        let [department, ...rest] = pool

        getInformation(department)
        .then(data => {
             myResult.push('something')
        })
        .catch(e => {})
        .finally(() => {
           search(rest, resolve, reject)
        })
}

const searchInDeps = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   search(departments, resolve, reject)
})

searchInDeps
.then(() => {
     // do something with myResult
})
.catch(e => {})
```

---

One other way as you need to loop, you can run each promises, and wait for the result of all.

```
let searches = []

for (i=0;i< departments.length;i++) {
  searches.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getInformation(departments[i])
        .then(data => {
             resolve('something')
        })
        .catch(e => resolve('something'))   
  })
}

Promise.all(searches)
.then(results => {
    // array of results
})
.catch(error => {})
```